# Join dataframe in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame as below

Data Frame 1

[image]

Data Frame 2

[image]

I would like to merge this two data frames into something like below;

[image]

I try to use pd.merge and join as below

```
frames = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['apple_id','apple_wgt_colour', 'apple_wgt_no_colour'])
```

But the result is like this one

[image]

Anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out the [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `concat()` and `groupby()`. Because you want to sum the corresponding values from apple_wgt_colour and apple_wgt_no_colour, you should use `agg()` to sum at the end.

You first should concat the two dataframes, then use `groupby` to aggreate the two columns, apple_wgt_colour and apple_wgt_no_colour.

```
# Generating the two dataframe you exampled.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'apple_id': [1, 2, 3],
        'apple_wgt_1': [9, 16, 8],
        'apple_wgt_colour': [9, 6, 8],
        'apple_wgt_no_colour': [0, 10, 13],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'apple_id': [1, 2, 3],
        'apple_wgt_2': [9, 16, 8],
        'apple_wgt_colour': [9, 6, 8],
        'apple_wgt_no_colour': [0, 10, 13],
    }
)

print(df1)
print(df2)

   apple_id  apple_wgt_1  apple_wgt_colour  apple_wgt_no_colour
0         1            9                 9                    0
1         2           16                 6                   10
2         3            8                 8                   13
   apple_id  apple_wgt_2  apple_wgt_colour  apple_wgt_no_colour
0         1            9                 9                    0
1         2           16                 6                   10
2         3            8                 8                   13
```

Next code will make a result you want:

```
frames = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('apple_id', as_index=False).agg(sum)

# to change column order as you want
frames = frames[['apple_id', 'apple_wgt_1', 'apple_wgt_2', 'apple_wgt_colour', 'apple_wgt_no_colour']]
print(frames)

   apple_id  apple_wgt_1  apple_wgt_2  apple_wgt_colour  apple_wgt_no_colour
0         1          9.0          9.0                18                    0
1         2         16.0         16.0                12                   20
2         3          8.0          8.0                16                   26
```

Comment: Definitely this is the answer I'm looking for! Thanks so much @Sangkeun Park